# Not able to access excel file

Tags: excel, vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview

[image]

I am importing data from excel file to datagridview in visual studio
There is an error prompted as

> Cannot update database or object is read-only

when I execute the program. The steps I have done so far

- Installed ACCESSDATABASE ENGINE
- PROVIDED THE SETTING TO VS FOR X86 PLATFORM USING CONFIG.MANAGER
- GRANTED THE CURRENT USER ALL THE PERMISSIONS REQUIRED USING RIGHT CLICK AND PROPERTIES OF THAT EXCEL FILE
  Is there any other way i can fix this problem??

[image: Screenshot Of Output]

```
Public Class ExcelData

Private Sub ExcelData_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Try

        Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim dataSet As System.Data.DataSet
        Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim path As String = "& TextBox2.text &"

        MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
        MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection)

        dataSet = New System.Data.DataSet
        MyCommand.Fill(dataSet)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables(0)

        MyConnection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
    End Try

End Sub
End Class
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8Ucp.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqLQq.png)

Comment: Show some of the code and where you're having an issue.

Comment: I have given the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

I could be incorrect about this but the line below looks odd…

```
Dim path As String = "& TextBox2.text &"
```

This creates a string called `path` that has the value: `& TextBox2.text &`…

Then you use this `path` string in the `OleDbConnection` with:

```
MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
```

In the line above you are trying to connect to a `DataSource` named "& TextBox2.text &…???

I am guessing from the code that text box on the form `TextBox2.Text` contains the full path to the Excel file you want to open. If this is the case then simply change the variable string `path` like below:

```
Dim path As String = TextBox2.Text
```

Just a thought.

Comment: Nope Not working bro...showing Invalid Arguments this time..  @JohnG

Comment: cant share u the pict here...wait will update the description and add pict in it

Comment: You are getting that error because of the line I pointed out in my answer. It is causing this error.

Comment: If you made the change as my answer posted... what error are you getting?

Comment: Invalid Argument

Comment: what line is throwing this error? Can you show the change you made?

Comment: See the images in the description i have uploaded 4 in total one of them is the changes you recommended.two links are there for image

Comment: I see you images and the code... none of them implement the change as I described in my answer.

Comment: Ok on the last screen shot... where do you get this error

Comment: There was no compile time error but the argument is passed at the place where you pass the value so not sure

Comment: I would double check the path and file. I copy and pasted your code made the change on the path and it works as expected. Maybe hard code the file name instead of getting it from a text box.

Comment: Ok wait will try